# sjg:grid with select with options =,<,> shows undefined

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid

Have sjg:grid in the jsp. Trying to add a column with a dropdown with options shown as =,<,> . But, in the dropdown it shows as = undefined < undefined undefined etc... .

How to get these option into the grid column dropdown. 
I tried the below

```
<s:url var="searchUrl" action="SearchAction"/>
<s:url var="editSearchUrl" action="editSearchAction"/>
<sjg:grid
    id="searchGridId"
  formIds="searchFormId"
  href="%{searchUrl}"
  reloadTopics="reloadSearchGrid"
  dataType="json" 
  pager="true"
  gridModel="searchResults"
  rowList="10,15,20"
  rowNum="15"
  rownumbers="true"
  viewrecords="true"
  autowidth="true"
  editurl="%{editSearchUrl}"
  editinline="true"
  navigator="true"
  navigatorAdd="false"
  navigatorViewOptions="{height:280, width:500}"
  navigatorDelete="false"
  navigatorEdit="false"
  navigatorRefresh="true"
  navigatorSearch="false"
  multiselect="false"
  onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
>       
    <sjg:gridColumn name="orderNumber" index="orderNumber" title="%  {getText('label.orderNumber')}" key="true" sortable="true"/>

    <sjg:gridColumn name="orderRange" index="orderRange" title="%{getText('label.orderRange)}" sortable="false" editable="true" edittype="select" editoptions="{value:'=:=;&lt;:&lt;;&gt;:&gt;'}"/>  
</sjg:grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this worked for me as suggested in this post

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/problem-using-colon-in-editoptions-as-value

```
editoptions="{dataUrl:'jsp/test.html'}"
```

test.html

```
<select role="select" id="orderRangeId" name="orderRange" size="1" class="editable">
    <option role="option" value="=">=</option>
    <option role="option" value="<"><</option>
    <option role="option" value=">">></option>
</select>
```